# AEM 6.1 Reference component references are not showing up in Classic UI

Tags: aem

Was going to the [AEM 6.1 Page-author](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/author-environment-tools.html) documentation for reference component. Strange is am not able to see any references link in Classic UI (i.e. via the sidekick Page tab -->Show References)

Steps to reproduce.

1. Drag and drop OOTB Text component in **/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men/coats** page and author some content.
2. Drag and drop OOTB Reference component in **/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/equipment** page
3. Edit the Reference component and select the text component that has been authored in above step-1.
4. Refreshed both the pages, And on **/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men/coats** page sidekick-->Page tab --> click on **Show References** Expected is to show a dialog popup with all the references available for that page.

*When i test the same with Touch UI it shows correctly the text under Lent Content section*

**Step1**[image: Step 1]
**Step2**[image: Step 2]
**Step3**

[image: Step 3]

**Step4**[image: Not Showing in Classic UI]
**Touch UI** [image: Touch UI]

Comment: It's plain and simple. The "references" in classic UI is strictly related to the references to the page itself rather than "lent content". 

So if you create a LINK to a page within another page it will be perceived as reference.

Classic and Touch aren't the same and will never be :)

Comment: Example if i create hyperlink to Equipments page in **coats** page Text component, The Show references in **coats** page should show the references of Equipment page.?

Comment: yes tried this one, but its exactly happening in a reverse way. i.e. it is showing in the **Equipment** page Show References dialog showing results of the coats page :(

Comment: damn. misread you. the references shows different pages where the CURRENT page is referenced. so your second comment is what I finally agree with. 
there is no native functionality having like "outside references" meaning "show me what other pages does my current page reference"  (at least not in classic UI)

Comment: yes, I agree your statement for Classic UI. The touch UI has both sections **Lent Content** & **Borrowed Content** under **CONTENT REFERENCES** section.